# Random number generation with GNU SGL library

Tags: c

How to generate the same effect for random number generation in GNU SGL like the following:

```
int ind = rand() % 2
```

i.e. generating either 0 or 1 exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can try this example:-

```
  #include <stdio.h>
 #include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>

 int
 main (void)
 {
   const gsl_rng_type * T;
   gsl_rng * r;

   int i, n = 10;

   gsl_rng_env_setup();

   T = gsl_rng_default;
   r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
     {
       double u = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
       printf ("%.5f\n", u);
     }

   gsl_rng_free (r);

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Yes. I have looked at this example but this is generating random numbers between 0 and 1 while I want to generate either 0 or 1 exact and at random. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this:- http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Sampling-from-a-random-number-generator.html ?

Comment: Yes but I don't get the point of setting the min and max values explicitly.

Comment: Welcome. Dont forget to accept the answer if that really answered your query. Happy coding!!